# Turn off Keyboard Repeating during install of Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, system-installation, virtualbox, keyboard, hardware

I am trying to install Ubuntu on VirtualBox over VPN using Remote Viewer and RDP and a slow internet connection.

For whatever reason this setup is causing me to have keys repeated.  So for example if I type UbuntuHost4 I get UUUUubunutttuuuHoooooooooooooost44444444444444

I am assuming it is not getting the KeyUp event fast enough through the lousy connection. I know I can disable the keyboard repeating after Ubuntu has been installed, but I am wondering if there is a way to disable the keyboard repeating during the setup process.